# Getting admin notices working for plugin errors

Tags: plugin-development, actions, notifications

I'm beginning with creating plugins and I don't quite understand the process of displaying error messages. e.g. I use the [php readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function to download a file from a hidden location. If something goes wrong e.g. the file isn't found, how do you display a message **at that moment**.

I know you need to use [add_action for 'admin_notices'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) but I can't quite figure out where you are supposed to put the add_action calls.

As far as I can tell, you have to create a function my_download_file which tries the download and echo's a `<div class="error">`. Then 'somewhere' you need to call `add_action('admin_notices', 'my_download file');`.

This, from reading the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), then gets called when admin_notices are being printed out. But does it always get called, or does it only get called when [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) gets called?

Comment: Why have the function download something and not just hard-code it into the plugin?

Comment: Its just an example, if I'm writing a system I want to be able to flash notices/errors to the user, I just can't figure out how to do it

Comment: You could try AJAX calls, WP has an excellent way to do it that you can find [explained here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: @Jared, thanks for your comments. What I'm trying to figure out is which plugin file should `add_action('admin_notices'...)` go into? Should it be put in the default file that is called by wordpress or somewhere else?

Comment: In a theme, code like that goes in the theme's `functions.php` file. In a plugin, that could essentially go anywhere as long as it's included in your main plugin file.

Comment: Can you selectively add an action? e.g. `if ($error) {add_action('admin_notices',...);}`, as my attempts failed.

Comment: What you would need to do is always run the `add_action`, and then in the function that is called in that action, do your conditional logic.

Comment: @Jared that's great, thank you. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do (as we discussed in comments) is run your conditional logic inside the function that that `add_action` calls. For example, you're adding an action to the `admin notices` hook.

The action will run, but the stuff inside that action's callback will only run if you let it.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'your_custom_function' );

function your_custom_function() {

    // You need some way to set (or retrieve) the value of your $error here (if not already set)

    if( $error ) {
        // Put everything here
    }

}
```

In a theme, this is typically found in your `functions.php` file or a file included in it. In a plugin, it could be in any file also as long as it is included in your main plugin file.

Comment: Does $error need to be a global variable? In php globals are generally frowned upon, but I can't think of any other way to handle a situation in which my conditional is dependent on another action (in my case a transition_post_status) I want to make sure an error is displayed, or is there a better way?